# Django_rest_framework Page Not Found

Tags: django, url, redirect, django-rest-framework

When I have been trying 127.0.0.1:8000/api/ it's working but when I've been trying 127.0.0.1:8000/api/rota it isn't working.

I don't know what is wrong. When linked urls.py files.

below the code of the the file:url.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls')),
    **path('api/', include('base.api.urls'))**,
]
I included the api/urls.py

below the code of the file: api/url.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',  views.getMessage),
    path('rota/', views.getRoutes),
]

I linked the url with  methods.
below the code of the file: api/view.py

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes=[
        'GET api/'
        'GET api/rota'
    ]
    return Response(routes)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getMessage(request):
    return Response("ok!")

Does someone know how to fix it?

Here some pictures about the case:

[127.0.0.1:8000/api/][1]
[127.0.0.1:8000/api/][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CoF.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5cok.png

I am looking for a solution...
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL to access the getRoutes view should be 127.0.0.1:8000/api/rota/